# How to make textmate work well with NFS?

Tags: macos, editor, textmate

I use and love textmate, but over NFS there's a large delay whenever one of its windows gains focus as it rescans all open files for changes. I've looked but not found any way to disable this feature.

Does anyone know of a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also get [ReMate](http://ciaranwal.sh/remate/) a plugin for TextMate that will allow for disabling of the Auto-Refresh.

It would be nice to be able to do this on a per-project basis, however.

Comment: Any sensible functionality is available in plugins... *sigh*

Comment: Note: the latest ReMate plugins will enable turning this on/off on a volume by volume basis, which is good enough for me.

Comment: Such a relief! I'm using NFS on a local VM (one that doesn't support vmware tools) and the refresh time was killlling me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about mac or NFS in general, but googling around showed me that you can try and play around with this NFS options on mac, assuming textmate stats the files to find out whether or not they have been changed:

```
nfs.client.statfs_rate_limit
nfs.lockd.host_monitor_cache_timeout
```

Let us know if it was any good.

See [the man page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/nfs.conf.5.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm reluctant to fiddle with my nfs settings... it's more than my editor that uses nfs.

Comment: And, it may be bad to set flags that give potentially misleading info to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there no such option. [See advance options that can be set](http://manual.macromates.com/en/expert_preferences#expert_preferences)
But you use rsync for ongoing projects and temporary edits this is not big issue.

Comment: I have tried a variant of this already (using git push/pull to do the rsync). But it's an extra step in the code/test cycle which I found worse than waiting for textmate.